# CSVParser [Apache] - why it is always ignoring first row (JAVA)

Tags: java, apache, csv

I don't understand why it is always ignoring first row... inputs:

```
b,a,c
x,f,ggg
```

also tried:

```
v,c,c
"v","xxx","x"
```

I am using this piece of code:

```
 public void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String text = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            text = text == null ? sb.toString() : text + "\n" + sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
            if (parserSet == false) {
                setParser(text, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader());
            }
        }
```

Where method setPaser is like:

```
 public void setParser(String textToParse, CSVFormat csvFormat) throws IOException {
     try {
        parserSet = true;
        this.textToParse = textToParse;
        CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(this.textToParse, csvFormat);
        records = parser;
        for (CSVRecord r: records) {
            System.out.println("Record: " + r);
            System.out.println("R(" + r.getRecordNumber() + "): " + r.get(0));
        }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT IS:

> Record: CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={b=0, a=1, c=2},
>   recordNumber=1, values=[x, x, tss]]
>
> R(1): x

So it seems it is always ignoring 1st row... I expected that recordNumber=1 will have values = [b,a,c] ... I need those values.

EDIT: In old way I was using record.toMap().entrySet(), from where I got 1st row values but they were in wrong order (exmaple b,a,c was returned as a,b,c) I need original order of values

Comment: Is it expecting the column names in the first row?

Comment: yes I want first row (its values - names) too (because I am creating SQL from CSV - needed for create table statement those values)

Comment: The headers are not in the records. You can get them with `parser.getHeaderMap()`.

Comment: seems to be working :D allright... I was trying to fix it almost 3 hours tried combinations and methods and nothing works, thanks god for stackOverflow people

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the parser there is a header:

```
setParser(text, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader());
```

So the first row is used for the column headers/names.